# Is firebase efficient with constant heavy updates

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Each client is reporting it's geolocation to our backend servers(Java)

We would like the server to update this param on firebase

```
Users/<userId>/location/<lon>,<lat>
```

We have 1M users which update their location in our scales: around  ~30,000 updates in a sec. so we need to update each change on firebase as it occurs.

Is firebase can  handle this load? 
should we tweak firebase client library on the server side to handle the load?